# Preventing certain things from being committed in XCode

Tags: xcode, svn

Situation: I have a few things in my code repository that I only want to be in my own working copy, but I still want to be able to modify the rest of the codebase and do commits without putting in those certain things I mentioned. Is it possible to lock those down in some way so they do not go in with the rest of my commit? Right now XCode commits everything that was modified. I realize I could commit files individually but it would be nice to continue to use the global commit.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try the [svn:ignore](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html) property (about half-way down the page)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could change the status of files to locked, then commit them without locked files. 
For SVN help, pls reference to http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

You should comment in "global-ignores" line in the configuration file located in ~/.subversion/config.

By this way you could ignore file types that you have given. I use the following set:

global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la #*# .*.rej *.rej .*~ *~ .#* .DS_Store *.mode1v3 *.pbxuser

Hope this helps.